# Is there a onShow method for a second controller?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I need a method to be ran (inside of my second controller) each time I run stage2.show(); I was originally doing this by using the initialize method, however this only works one time.

```
hello-view.fxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox fx:id="vbox" alignment="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#onVboxClick" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.orderingapp.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorpane" onMouseClicked="#onVboxClick" prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="968.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="nameField" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="23.0" onAction="#enterName" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="378.0" promptText="Enter your name" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="59.0" prefHeight="174.0" prefWidth="220.0" />
            <ImageView fx:id="logo" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="47.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <TextField fx:id="addressField" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="87.0" onAction="#enterAddress" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="378.0" promptText="Enter your address" />
            <TextField fx:id="cityField" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="158.0" onAction="#enterCity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" promptText="Enter your city" />
            <TextField fx:id="zipField" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="158.0" onAction="#enterZip" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Zipcode" />
            <TextField fx:id="stateField" layoutX="421.0" layoutY="158.0" onAction="#enterState" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" promptText="State" />
            <Label fx:id="nameLabel" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="378.0" text="Name:" />
            <Label fx:id="addressLabel" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="378.0" text="Address:" />
            <Label fx:id="cityLabel" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="City:" />
            <Label fx:id="stateLabel" layoutX="421.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="111.0" text="State:" />
            <Label fx:id="zipLabel" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Zip:" />
            <Separator layoutY="254.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="962.0" />
            <Separator layoutX="240.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="244.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
            <Separator layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="232.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="dateLabel" alignment="CENTER" editable="false" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="memoryTypes" layoutY="355.0" onAction="#memoryTypeSelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Type" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="mouseTypes" layoutY="395.0" onAction="#mouseTypeSelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Type" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="driveTypes" layoutY="435.0" onAction="#driveTypeSelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Type" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="boardQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="275.0" onAction="#boardQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="cardQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="315.0" onAction="#cardQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="memoryQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="355.0" onAction="#memoryQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="mouseQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="395.0" onAction="#mouseQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="driveQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="435.0" onAction="#driveQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="monitorQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="475.0" onAction="#monitorQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="desktopQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="515.0" onAction="#desktopQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="laptopQuantity" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="555.0" onAction="#laptopQuantitySelect" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="0" />
            <Separator layoutX="640.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="244.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Monster Mother Boards" />
            <TextField fx:id="boardCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="boardPrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="boardProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="boardSubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="GForce Graphics Cards" />
            <TextField fx:id="cardCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="cardPrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="cardProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="cardSubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="355.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Monster Memory Sticks" />
            <TextField fx:id="memoryCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="355.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="memoryPrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="355.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="memoryProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="355.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="memorySubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="355.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="395.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Wacky Wireless Mouse" />
            <TextField fx:id="mouseCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="395.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="mousePrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="395.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="mouseProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="395.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="mouseSubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="395.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="435.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Hard Drive(s) 500 GB" />
            <TextField fx:id="driveCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="435.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="drivePrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="435.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="driveProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="435.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="driveSubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="435.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="475.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="ACME Monitor" />
            <TextField fx:id="monitorCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="475.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="monitorPrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="475.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="monitorProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="475.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="monitorSubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="475.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="515.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="ACME Desktop PC" />
            <TextField fx:id="desktopCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="515.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="desktopPrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="515.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="desktopProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="515.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="desktopSubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="515.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField editable="false" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="554.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="ACME Laptop PC" />
            <TextField fx:id="laptopCosts" editable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="554.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="laptopPrices" editable="false" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="554.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="laptopProfits" editable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="554.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="laptopSubtotal" editable="false" layoutX="643.0" layoutY="554.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="0.00" />
            <Separator layoutX="732.0" layoutY="262.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
            <Label layoutY="254.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Types:" />
            <Label layoutX="94.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Quantities:" />
            <Label layoutX="196.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Items:" />
            <Label layoutX="361.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Unit Cost:" />
            <Label layoutX="458.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Retail Price:" />
            <Label layoutX="550.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Profit:" />
            <Label layoutX="643.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Subtotal:" />
            <TextField fx:id="cumulativeQuantities" editable="false" layoutX="803.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" promptText="Cumulative Quantity (Day)" text="0" />
            <TextField fx:id="cumulativeProfits" editable="false" layoutX="803.0" layoutY="158.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" promptText="Cumulative Profit (Day)" text="0" />
            <Label layoutX="649.0" layoutY="18.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Cumulative Day's Quantity:" />
            <Label layoutX="649.0" layoutY="154.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Cumulative Day's Profit:" />
            <Label layoutX="738.0" layoutY="279.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Sales Tax:" />
            <Label layoutX="738.0" layoutY="319.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Order With Tax:" />
            <Label layoutX="738.0" layoutY="359.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Processing Fee's:" />
            <Label layoutX="738.0" layoutY="399.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Order Total:" />
            <TextField fx:id="salesTaxes" editable="false" layoutX="830.0" layoutY="278.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="orderWithTaxes" editable="false" layoutX="830.0" layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="processFees" editable="false" layoutX="830.0" layoutY="355.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="orderTotals" editable="false" layoutX="830.0" layoutY="395.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="0.00" />
            <AnchorPane layoutX="738.0" layoutY="395.0" />
            <Button fx:id="quit" layoutX="832.0" layoutY="448.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onQuit" text="Quit" />
            <Button fx:id="clearOrder" layoutX="744.0" layoutY="448.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClearOrder" text="Clear Order" />
            <Separator layoutX="744.0" layoutY="434.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="214.0" />
            <Button fx:id="print" layoutX="883.0" layoutY="448.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onPrint" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Print" />
            <Button fx:id="calculate" layoutX="748.0" layoutY="478.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onCalculate" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="207.0" text="Calculate">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Separator layoutX="738.0" layoutY="514.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="214.0" />
            <Label layoutX="738.0" layoutY="519.0" text="Profit Total:" />
            <Label layoutX="738.0" layoutY="559.0" text="Subtotal Total:" />
            <TextField fx:id="profitTotals" editable="false" layoutX="830.0" layoutY="515.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="0.00" />
            <TextField fx:id="subtotalTotals" editable="false" layoutX="830.0" layoutY="554.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="0.00" />
            <ComboBox layoutY="475.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Default" />
            <ComboBox layoutY="515.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Default" visibleRowCount="0" />
            <ComboBox layoutY="555.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Default" visibleRowCount="0" />
            <ComboBox layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Default" />
            <ComboBox layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" promptText="Default" />
            <TextField fx:id="memberField" layoutX="417.0" layoutY="219.0" onAction="#onEnterMember" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="214.0" promptText="Enter member ID" visible="false" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="memberCheck" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="223.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#checkMember" text="Are you a member?" />
            <Label fx:id="memberLabel" layoutX="417.0" layoutY="202.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="214.0" text="Enter your member ID" visible="false" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>

hello-view2.fxml

(imports)

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="423.0" prefWidth="575.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" fx:controller="com.example.orderingapp.HelloController2">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="490.0" prefWidth="535.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="label" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="535.0" text="Label">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

```
HelloController.java

package com.example.orderingapp;

// all my imports

public class HelloController
{
    // all of my FXML objects and variables

    public Stage stage2 = new Stage();
    public FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view2.fxml"));

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        Image img = new Image(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("laptop.png")));
        logo.setImage(img);
        // sets text for all of them (deleted for character limits)
        // Creates ComboBox options for laptops.
        laptopCosts.setText(String.valueOf(laptopCost));
        laptopPrices.setText(String.valueOf(laptopPrice));
        laptopProfits.setText(String.valueOf(laptopProfit));
        // Adds numbers 0 to 10 for each quantity ComboBox.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            monitorQuantity.getItems().add(i);
            desktopQuantity.getItems().add(i);
            laptopQuantity.getItems().add(i);
            boardQuantity.getItems().add(i);
            cardQuantity.getItems().add(i);
            memoryQuantity.getItems().add(i);
            mouseQuantity.getItems().add(i);
            driveQuantity.getItems().add(i);
        }
        // Creates ComboBox options for each drive type.
        driveTypes.getItems().addAll("Type", "IDE", "SATA", "SSD");
        // Creates ComboBox options for each mouse type.
        mouseTypes.getItems().addAll("Type", "Blue", "Black", "Pink");
        // Creates ComboBox options for each memory type.
        memoryTypes.getItems().addAll("Type", "32GB", "64GB", "128GB");

        // sets all quantity variables to 0

        // Gets the date
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        // Gets the time
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
        int min = time.getMinute();
        int hr = time.getHour();
        String timeString = "";
        String PmAm = "";
        // Checks if time is AM or PM
        // If the time is exactly 12, then there is no need to subtract 12.
        if (hr == 12)
        {
            PmAm = "PM";
        }
        if (hr < 12)
        {
            PmAm = "AM";
        }
        // If the time is PM, then subtract 12 (13 in military time (13-12) is 1 in normal time)
        if (hr > 12)
        {
            PmAm = "PM";
            hr = hr - 12;
        }
        // Adds the : and a Zero if the current time is not a double-digit number.
        if (min < 10)
        {
            timeString = hr + ":0" + min + " " + PmAm;
        } else {
            timeString = hr + ":" + min + " " + PmAm;
        }
        orderTime = timeString;
        // Sets the date label
        dateLabel.setText(date + " | " + timeString);
        // Initializes every value to zero
        onClearOrder();
        nameField.requestFocus();
    }

    public double calculate(int quant, int val, double sub, double price, TextField text)
    {
        // Calculates the price
        String rounded = "";
        quant = val;
        sub = price * quant;
        // Rounds the price to the hundredths place
        rounded = twoPlaces.format(sub);
        // Sets the text to the rounded value
        text.setText(rounded);
        // Returns the price (unrounded)
        return sub;
    }

    @FXML
    public void boardQuantitySelect()
    {
        // Gets and Sets the quantity
        boardQuant = boardQuantity.getValue();
        // Calculates the subtotal
        boardSub = calculate(boardQuant, boardQuantity.getValue(), boardSub, boardPrice, boardSubtotal);
    }

    @FXML
    public void cardQuantitySelect()
    {
        // all quantity selects are same as the motherboard one
    }

    @FXML
    public void desktopQuantitySelect()
    {
       // same as others
    }

    @FXML
    public void driveQuantitySelect()
    {
        // same as others
    }

    @FXML
    public void driveTypeSelect()
    {
        // Gets the index of the currently selected item
        int index = driveTypes.getItems().indexOf(driveTypes.getValue());
        // Sets the selected item values based off of the current index
        selectedDriveCost = driveCost[index];
        selectedDrivePrice = drivePrice[index];
        selectedDriveProfit = driveProfit[index];
        // Sets the text
        driveCosts.setText(String.valueOf(selectedDriveCost));
        drivePrices.setText(String.valueOf(selectedDrivePrice));
        driveProfits.setText(String.valueOf(selectedDriveProfit));
        // Calculates the subtotal
        driveSub = calculate(driveQuant, driveQuantity.getValue(), driveSub, selectedDrivePrice, driveSubtotal);
    }

    @FXML
    public void enterAddress()
    {
        // Sets and gets the address
        address = addressField.getText();
    }

    @FXML
    public void enterCity()
    {
        // Sets and gets the city
        city = cityField.getText();
    }

    @FXML
    public void enterName()
    {
        // Sets and gets the name
        name = nameField.getText();
    }

    @FXML
    public void enterState()
    {
        // Sets and gets the state
        state = stateField.getText();
    }

    @FXML
    public void enterZip()
    {
        // Sets and gets the zipcode
        if(isDigit(zipField.getText()))
        {
            zip = zipField.getText();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void laptopQuantitySelect()
    {
        // same as others
    }

    @FXML
    public void memoryQuantitySelect()
    {
        // same as others
    }

    @FXML
    public void memoryTypeSelect()
    {
        // same as other type select
    }

    @FXML
    public void monitorQuantitySelect()
    {
        // same as others
    }

    @FXML
    public void mouseQuantitySelect()
    {
        // same as others

    @FXML
    public void mouseTypeSelect()
    {
        // same as other type select
    }

    @FXML
    public void onCalculate()
    {
        // Sets values to 0
        processFee = 0.00;
        orderTotal = 0.00;
        // Calculates the total of all the subtotals
        subtotalTotal = boardSub + cardSub + memorySub + mouseSub + driveSub + monitorSub + desktopSub + laptopSub;
        // Calculates sales tax (rate is 6%)
        salesTax = subtotalTotal * 0.06;
        // adds the total of all subtotals to the just calculated sales tax amount
        orderWithTax = subtotalTotal + salesTax;
        // Checks if the user is a member
        if (!isMember)
        {
            String rounded = "";
            // If the user is not a member, then the process fee is 1.5%
            orderTotal = orderWithTax;
            processFee = orderWithTax * 0.015;
            orderTotal += processFee;
            // Rounds each value and sets text
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(subtotalTotal);
            subtotalTotals.setText(rounded);
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(salesTax);
            salesTaxes.setText(rounded);
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(orderWithTax);
            orderWithTaxes.setText(rounded);
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(orderTotal);
            orderTotals.setText(rounded);
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(processFee);
            processFees.setText(rounded);
        } else
        {
            // If the user IS a member, then there is no process fee.
            orderTotal = orderWithTax;
            String rounded = "";
            // Rounds and sets text.
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(subtotalTotal);
            subtotalTotals.setText(rounded);
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(salesTax);
            salesTaxes.setText(rounded);
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(orderWithTax);
            orderWithTaxes.setText(rounded);
            rounded = twoPlaces.format(orderTotal);
            orderTotals.setText(rounded);
            orderTotal = orderWithTax;
            processFee = 0;
            processFees.setText("0.00");
        }
        // Initializes profit total to 0
        profitTotal = 0;
        // Calculates the profit total
        profitTotal += boardProfit * boardQuant;
        // adds the rest of the profits to the profit total
    }

    @FXML
    public void onEnterMember()
    {
        // Gets the user's member ID
        isMember = !(memberField.getText().isBlank()) && isDigit(memberField.getText());
    }

    @FXML
    public void checkMember()
    {
        // Makes the member display text and member text field to be visible or invisible based off the checkbox.
        memberLabel.setVisible(memberCheck.isSelected());
        memberField.setVisible(memberCheck.isSelected());
    }

    @FXML
    public void onClearOrder()
    {
        // Initializes all quantities to zero
        
        // Initializes all types to nothing
        
        // Initializes all subtotals to 0
        
        // Resets user information to empty
        
        // Set member check box to false
        memberCheck.setSelected(false);
        // Set booleans to false
        
        // Close the invoice window
        stage2.close();
        // Sets the current selection of all quantiy combo boxes to 0
        
        // Sets the current selection of all types to the default value.
        memoryTypes.valueProperty().set("Type");
        // others were cut out

        // Initializes the profit total, sales tax, process fee, order total, order with tax, and total of all subtotals to 0
        
        // Clears the text.
        
    }

    @FXML
    public void onPrint() throws IOException
    {
        // If the order is the same as the last order, then set the isOld order boolean to true
        if(oldTotal == orderWithTax)
        {
            isOld = true;
        } else {
            isOld = false;
        }
        // If the order is not the same as the old order, then calculate the cumulative values.
        if(!isOld)
        {
            cumulativeProfit += profitTotal;
            cumulativeQuantity += (boardQuant + cardQuant + memoryQuant + mouseQuant + driveQuant + monitorQuant + desktopQuant + laptopQuant);
        }
        // Sets the old total to the current total
        oldTotal = orderWithTax;
        // Rounds and sets text
        String rounded = "";
        rounded = twoPlaces.format(profitTotal);
        profitTotals.setText(rounded);
        rounded = twoPlaces.format(cumulativeProfit);
        // Sets text for cumulative profits and cumulative quantities.
        cumulativeProfits.setText(rounded);
        cumulativeQuantities.setText(String.valueOf(cumulativeQuantity));
        if(!windowOpened)
        {
            staticStorage.set(boardPrice, cardPrice, selectedMemoryPrice, selectedMousePrice, selectedDrivePrice, monitorPrice, desktopPrice, laptopPrice,
                    boardQuant, cardQuant, memoryQuant, mouseQuant, driveQuant, monitorQuant, desktopQuant, laptopQuant, orderTotal, orderTime, name, address,
                        city, state, zip);
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
            stage2.setScene(scene);
            stage2.setTitle("Stage 2");
            stage2.show();
            windowOpened = true;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void onQuit()
    {
        // Exits the program
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @FXML
    public void onVboxClick(MouseEvent event)
    {

    }

    public boolean isDigit(String s)
    {
        // Initialize Boolean
        boolean x = false;
        // Test if parsing will create an error
        try{
            // If parsing throws no errors, then the program will say that the input IS a digit (true)
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            x = true;
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            x = false;
            // If parsing does create an error, then the program will say that the input is not a digit (false)
        }
        // The program then returns the value.
        return x;
    }
}
```

```
HelloController2.java

package com.example.orderingapp;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController2
{
    @FXML
    public Label label;

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        label.setText("Invoice");
        label.setText("Motherboard quantity: " + staticStorage.boardQuant);
    }
}
```

```
staticStorage.java
public class staticStorage
{
    // all vars

    public static void set(// arguments to set everything)
    {
        // im past max chars but this sets everything
    }
}
```

The static storage class is used so that I can share data between my controllers.

I tried to use the initialize method but this only works once, because the stage is only initialized once. I tried searching for an onShow method but all I could find was stage2.setOnShowing(event);
None of these worked.

Comment: The `initialize()` method is called on the corresponding controller each time the FXML file is loaded via `FXMLLoader.load()`. It has nothing to do with the stage. It's not really clear what you mean here. Create and post a complete [mre] which demonstrates the problem (i.e. an example which shows where you want `initialize()` to be called but isn't being called).

Comment: I need the initialize method to be called after stage2.show() is called within the onPrint method in the HelloController1.java class

Comment: Keep a reference to the controller after loading the FXML, and call `stage2.setOnShown(e -> controller.initialize());`. If all you're doing is updating the view from the data, it's probably better to use a MVC approach here (with observable properties in the model, so the controller can observe them and update the label itself). But again, create and post a [mre] so it's clear what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for posting this kind of question. Although you have a valid question, please consider reducing your code snippets to only include a minimum viable example so that community member don't have to shuffle through large blocks of code to assist you. The next comment will provide links to help you improve this post, and hopefully, community members will respond by helping you out.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).